# how can one access window object of a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, browser

How can I get the window object of a web-page in java.My question is that "**Is there any method to get the window object of a web-page in java ?** ".

Comment: No not really, you could get a representation of the object but never the object itself. What exactly do you want to do? There's bound to be a solution ;)

Comment: Explain what you want, this crypto short responses and question is not helping you. Details!!

Comment: By event listener I mean the event of button click or hyperlink event . I want to add listener because I want to access the URL of the button event and create an URL Connection to that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java is to JavaScript as Ham is to Hamster](http://www.flickr.com/photos/schrader/3779250024/)

Java on the backend has no way of getting reference to the window object. It is like having a hard copper phone line between the Earth and Mars. I am not sure why you would need it there anyway.

If you are talking about applets, you have the [JSObject](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html) which can access the DOM.